# React hooks - How to implement shoulComponentUpdate method in a functional component which checks for both state and props?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to implement `shouldComponenetUpdate` using React Hooks. All the answers that I came across suggest `React.memo` as the way to do it, but `React.memo` second argument takes `prevProps` and `nextProps` as the arguments, whereas I want to check my condition based on states.

Any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Not completely true, `React.memo` is a type of component that will do a shallow compare.

Depending on what you want the rerender to take into account, you could use hooks like `useMemo`, `useCallback`, `useEffect`

They work as follows:

`const bla = useMemo(() => { return computeSomeValue() }, []);`

the second argument are the dependencies (deps).
These are compared shallowly when the component should rerender, if no change is there, `bla` will not be recalculated and the component will not be updated.

So lets say we have a dependency on some property, you could do

`const bla = useMemo(() => { return computeSomeValue(myProperty) }, [myProperty]);`

Answer (score 0):

If your state change your component has already rendered. Use `React.useRef` if you want to have a "saved state" that doesn't trigger a render.

You can learn more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref